# Line-height doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically center my text with my logo. When I use line height, it also raises my logo. How could I just raise the text so it's vertically centered with my logo? Here's my code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li> dfgkdfjg </li>
            <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/d0umnxt.png" /></li>
            <li> pfopkp </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#header {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #151B1F;
}
#nav {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav li {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are trying to align the text which will creates problem for you; instead of aligning the text try to align the image ...

Add this in your css

```
#nav img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is working example [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yyg2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to vertical align the image instead of the text:

```css
#nav img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This will do the job.